# Что изучить после книги Страуструпа по с++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, книги

Я студент второго курса.
Дочитываю книгу Cтрауструпа по с++. 
Мне кажется, что прочитав книжку только по языку-ты делаешь верный шаг быдлокодера, ведь по любому нужны еще книжки (ну и практика само собой), например по алгоритмам, логике и тому подобное. Может стоит изучить еще что то, например Базы данных.

Что вы можете посоветовать изучить, в каком порядке?

/ *А то я чувствую себя маленьким цыпленком в огромном мире программирования, и не знаю куда двигаться, что бы потом не называли индусом или быдлокодером:)*/

Comment: Ну так в чем проблема? Берем книги по математике (то, что у вас в институте преподают, изучи поглубже), по алгоритмам (книг навалом), паттернам, операционным системам, железу и пр. И вперед.

Comment: А что касается "назовут индусом или быдлокодером" -- так надо просто заучить один коротенький адрес и называющим рекомендовать отправиться туда. Сам адрес здесь привести не могу по цензурным соображениям.

Comment: @alexlz, вы имели ввиду GTFO?

Comment: @VladD и @teanЫЧ Да. Совет совершить пешее эротическое путешествие.

Comment: @ХэшКод: вы правы в том, что единственного верного ответа не существует, но мне кажется, дополнительные ответы на этот вопрос были бы на пользу сайту.

Comment: @avp: (там комментарии закончились) Спасибо!

Comment: @andrw, там (писал про ассемблер) комментарии закончились. 

Вот если интересен "нижний уровень" (архитектура компа, ассемблер) вспомнил **[замечательный](http://www.wasm.ru/article.php?article=1022001) ресурс**. 

Там еще очень много полезных статей.

Comment: @avp Ещё более низкий уровень -- листинг микропрограмм процессора с микропрограммным управлением :) 

Вспомнилось из мини-эвм (в pdp11 такого уже не было) -- "команда-микропрограмма". На ассемблере она д.б. занимать несколько строк.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и другая литература по С++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Мне кажется, кроме книг важна и практика.

Читайте чужой код, старайтесь понять *каждую* строчку, достоинства и недостатки, спрашивайте опытных коллег, не стесняйтесь показаться нубом. Вырабатывайте стиль, учитесь отличать плохой код от хорошего.

Попробуйте написать свой (интересный вам) проект, не сильно сложный для начала. Пишите его как можно правильнее, умейте обосновать ваши решения. Растите над собой. Всё равно через 2 года старый код всегда кажется плохим (если нет, вы не растёте над собой и это плохо).

Выберете предметную область (графика, базы данных, сетевые технологии, сайты, вычисления, что угодно) и совершенствуйтесь в ней. Пробуйте ответить на все вопросы тут и на StackOverflow по данной тематике, читайте чужие ответы. Дискутируйте! Выясняйте, почему чужие ответы лучше (или хуже). Обязательно выучите английский, чтобы свободно читать документацию (её в разы больше на английском!) и общаться на SO (а также при случае и с заграничными заказчиками).

---

По поводу книг: по C++ я бы посоветовал Брюса Эккеля ["Философия С++"](http://mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html). Когда осилите, читайте что угодно Скотта Майерса, Херба Саттера и Андрея Александреску, они затащат вас в мир современного программирования, и мы все будем казаться вам динозаврами.

Мне как-то помогли разобраться в основах и дисциплинировать мышление "Алгоритмы и структуры данных" Никлауса Вирта. Учтите, диалект Паскаля, на котором он пишет там, далёк от современности, но правильному пониманию структурного программирования книга научит.

Если хотите развиваться в мир управляемых языков (не самая плохая идея, кстати), я бы посоветовал Албахари "C# x.x in a Nutshell", Джона Скита "C# in Depth" (отличная штука!). По Java отличая книга Джошуа Блоха "Java. Эффективное программирование", маст рид.

Если хотите знать нижний уровень (как всё на самом деле устроено) для настоящих индейцев, читайте что угодно Джеффри Рихтера (по всем направлениям). Но учтите: это изменит ваше сознание почище наркотиков. :) Одноклассники вот ещё советуют Арта Бейкера, для понимания уровня драйверов.

Из книг, которые меняют мироощущение, просто нельзя не назвать Абельсона/Сассмана "Структура и интерпретация компьютерных программ". Она об очень высокоуровневых штуках, понимании того, что же такое программирование. Когда осилите, достигнете дзена. Мозговые вирусы "Хаскель" и "Лисп" идут в комплекте.

Ну и обязательная ссылка на основоположника Вообще Всего Дональда Кнута: стащите в библиотеке "Искусство программирования" в хорошем переводе и почитайте. Он сложный и умопомрачительно офигенный, я предупреждал.

Comment: Да, читать чужой код это полезно. Главное, чтобы он был **хороший**. Только тема (для чего написан код) должна быть достаточно знакома, иначе ничего толком не поймете.

И совет попробовать отвечать тут на вопросы правильный. Пока будете разбираться со многими областями познакомитесь.

По поводу книг, попробуйте почитать Т. Пратта "Языки программирования. Разработка и реализация" и чего-нибудь по операционным системам. Алгоритмы. Потом возьмитесь за ассемблер и статьи (в сети их полно) по архитектуре (система команд, кэши, память и т.п.) компьютеров. 

Думаю, книги примерно в таком прядке.

Comment: @avp: Я ожидал от вас совета по поводу ассемблера :) Посоветуете какую-нибудь книгу по ассемблеру, архитектуре машин и всему такому? (Может лучше отдельным ответом, мой +1 у вас уже считайте есть.) А то я в ассемблере полный чайник.

Comment: @avp Читать хороший код сейчас, чтобы потом читать плохой... А из книг по чтению чужого кода -- http://mirknig.com/2012/10/04/teoriya-i-praktika-strukturnogo-programmirovaniya.html В своё время сильно поразила моё воображение. @VladD народ считает одним из лучших ассемблеров (фаны -- лучшим) macro-11. Смотреть начиная с www.pdp11.org (я на нём уже не писал. Любовь к ассемблеру у меня прошла раньше, чем я с этой архитектурой столкнулся).

А из языков посоветовал бы haskell -- как-никак фронтир.

Comment: @alexlz: да, к сожалению, больше попадается плохого кода, чем хорошего. :( Уметь вычленить из него идею -- то ещё искусство, посложнее, чем получать эстетическое наслаждение от совершенного кода. А какую книгу вы бы посоветовали?

Comment: @VladD ссылка в предыдущем комментарии. http://mirknig.com/2012/10/04/teoriya-i-praktika-strukturnogo-programmirovaniya.html (скачивается или нет -- я не проверял. У меня она где-то бумажная есть). Ежели мне не изменяет склероз, там есть упражнение: дан код, найти ошибку. :)))

Comment: @alexlz: я имел в виду по ассемблеру и архитектурам. И по Хаскелю :) PS: отличные упражнения! На таких и надо учиться.

Comment: Давно я по ассемблеру ничего не читал, да и не писал (ничего больше нескольких строк) на нем уже лет 20...

Насчет macro-11 (pdp) абсолютно согласен с @alexlz. Дома у меня лежит книжка по нему, но названия не помню (вечером кину, но вот удастся ли саму ее найти???).

А тут недавно были вопросы про ассемблер. Возможно в ответах есть ссылки на литературу.

Comment: @VladD, Вы основательно дополнили свой ответ. Жаль, что второй раз нельзя отметить.

Comment: @avp: спасибо! Когда написал, пришло в голову ещё, потом ещё, итого пока 18 версий.

Comment: Ну по Хаскелю http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Books. Правда ссылок на Душкина я там почему-то не нашёл -- это к гуглу. Архитектуры? pdp11 -- тоже ссылка была. Про x51 -- гугл (как-никак десятки производителей и сотни типов контроллеров, так что книг д.б. много). А в x51 есть битовая память...

Comment: @VladD Душкинhttp://progbook.ru/haskell/824-dushkin-funkcionalnoe-programmirovanie-na-yazyke.html. А SICP теперь вроде на питоне...

Comment: Как обещал книга по macro-11.

М. Cингер  "Мини ЭВМ PDP-11: программирование не языке ассемблера и организация машины". Москва, Мир 1984.